# netsh doesn't provide commands

Tags: networking, windows-7, scripting, powershell, netsh

According to [Netsh Commands for Wired Local Area Network (LAN) in Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732869(v=ws.10).aspx), netsh should provide commands such as

```
netsh add profile filename="profile.xml" interface="Local Area Connection"
```

but that's an unknown command for my netsh.

Even if I enter

```
netsh show /?
```

it shows me only two options: 'show alias' and 'show helper'. Maybe some library/modules or something is missing?

I tested with admin permissions in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be in the 'lan' context of netsh for the profile commands to be accessible:

```
C:\Users\kce>netsh lan add profile /?

Usage:  add profile [filename=]<string>  [interface=]<string>

Parameters:

   filename  - name of the profile XML file
   interface - interface name

Remarks:

   Parameter filename is required.
   It is the name of the XML file containing the profile data.

   Parameter interface is optional. It is one of the interface name shown
   by "netsh lan show interface" command. If interface name is given,
   the profile will be added to the specified interface, otherwise the
   profile will be added on all wired interfaces.

Examples:

   add profile filename="Profile1.xml" interface="Local Area Connection"


C:\Users\kce>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
netsh /?
```

will show you all the available options for the command.